# Delphi: Erro 80020101 ao executar javascript no TWebbrowser

Tags: javascript, delphi, navegador-de-internet

Utilizo o `TWebbrowser` em uma aplicação `Delphi XE7`, mas estou tendo problemas ao tentar executar comandos `javascript`.

> (OleException ... Não possível concluir a operação Erro: 80020101 )

Isso acontece com qualquer função que eu tente executar, seja minha ou jquery por exemplo, ao que parece a função nem chega a ser executada. O procedimento que uso para executar é o seguinte: 
[How to call JavaScript functions in a TWebBrowser from Delphi](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=21&part=1#solution) 
em meu caso, tenho a função:

```
        function colaNota () {

        $('#corpo').append($('<div id="' + new_nota_id + '">' + new_nota_bar + '<p>' + new_nota_texto + '</p><div/>').addClass('notas ui-widget-content').css({
            left: new_nota_x,
            top: new_nota_y }));

        controlaBarraMensagens('oculto');          
        $( ".notas" ).draggable();
        $("#corpo").removeClass("inserindo");
        $("#sub_indice_mold").removeClass("visivel");
        clearNota();
    };
```

No delphi estou chamando assim:

```
JSFn := 'colaNota();';  //Assim não funciona
JSFn := 'alert("Assim funciona");';

HTMLWindow.execScript(JSFn, 'JavaScript');
```

Comment: edita a pergunta e posta uma das funções

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de resolver isso:

```html
      Try
          WebBrowser1.Silent :=True;
          //seu código aqui

      Except
        On E:Exception Do Begin
          MessageDlg('Houve um erro ao lentar ler o arquivo : '+E.Message,mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
        End;
     end;
```

Comment: Apenas para finalizar, esse erro estava acontecendo devido as funções não estarem visíveis para o delphi pois estavam dentro de $(document).ready

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de erro ocorreu comigo também. E a forma de elimina-lo foi corrigundo o JavaScript, pois parecia estar com erro. Tipo No JS estava desta forma ( umavar = 10;) mas ela deveria ser uma chamada de função e não uma var e quando fiz isto ( umavar(10);) o JS ficou certo e parou de dar erro, descrito acima.